Why is the process spawning separately from the pseudo console?
I'm trying to create a pseudo console running a command line in rust, using this guide as a reference.
However, the process that is supposed to be spawned into the console gets spawned separately (in another window, and ClosePseudoConsole has no effect on it).
Am I doing something wrong?
use std::{ffi::OsStr, os::windows::ffi::OsStrExt};

use windows::{
    core::{Error, PWSTR},
    Win32::{
        Foundation::{CloseHandle, HANDLE},
        System::{
            Console::{ClosePseudoConsole, CreatePseudoConsole, COORD, HPCON},
            Memory::{GetProcessHeap, HeapAlloc},
            Pipes::CreatePipe,
            Threading::{
                CreateProcessW, InitializeProcThreadAttributeList, UpdateProcThreadAttribute,
                EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT, LPPROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_LIST, PROCESS_INFORMATION,
                PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_PSEUDOCONSOLE, STARTUPINFOEXW,
            },
        },
    },
};
pub struct PTY {
    input_read_side: HANDLE,
    input_write_side: HANDLE,
    output_read_side: HANDLE,
    output_write_side: HANDLE,
    pi: PROCESS_INFORMATION,
    hpcon: HPCON,
}

impl PTY {
    pub unsafe fn new(size: COORD, cmd_line: &OsStr) -> Result<Self, Error> {
        let (mut input_read_side, mut input_write_side) = (HANDLE::default(), HANDLE::default());
        CreatePipe(&mut input_read_side, &mut input_write_side, None, 0)?;
        let (mut output_read_side, mut output_write_side) = (HANDLE::default(), HANDLE::default());
        CreatePipe(&mut output_read_side, &mut output_write_side, None, 0)?;
        let hpcon = CreatePseudoConsole(size, input_read_side, output_write_side, 0)?;

        let mut startup_info_ex = std::mem::zeroed::<STARTUPINFOEXW>();
        startup_info_ex.StartupInfo.cb = std::mem::size_of::<STARTUPINFOEXW>() as u32;

        let mut bytes_required: usize = 0;
        // This is expected to fail
        let _ = InitializeProcThreadAttributeList(
            LPPROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_LIST::default(),
            1,
            0,
            &mut bytes_required,
        );

        let hheap = GetProcessHeap()?;
        startup_info_ex.lpAttributeList = LPPROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_LIST(HeapAlloc(
            hheap,
            windows::Win32::System::Memory::HEAP_FLAGS(0),
            bytes_required,
        ));

        InitializeProcThreadAttributeList(
            startup_info_ex.lpAttributeList,
            1,
            0,
            &mut bytes_required,
        )?;

        UpdateProcThreadAttribute(
            startup_info_ex.lpAttributeList,
            0,
            PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_PSEUDOCONSOLE as usize,
            Some((&hpcon as *const _) as *const _),
            std::mem::size_of::<HPCON>(),
            None,
            None,
        )?;

        let mut cmd_line = cmd_line.encode_wide().chain(Some(0)).collect::<Vec<_>>();
        let mut pi = std::mem::zeroed::<PROCESS_INFORMATION>();
        CreateProcessW(
            None,
            PWSTR(cmd_line.as_mut_ptr()),
            None,
            None,
            false,
            EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT,
            None,
            None,
            &startup_info_ex.StartupInfo,
            &mut pi,
        )?;

        Ok(Self {
            input_read_side,
            input_write_side,
            output_read_side,
            output_write_side,
            pi,
            hpcon,
        })
    }
}


I tried passing STARTUPINFOEXW directly, instead of its property. I did this by casting its pointer to the type CreateProcessW requests, however, no effect.
I tried giving UpdateProcThreadAttribute the input_write_side handle, and that stopped spawning the process separately. But Im uncertain if it actually... did something? Because when reading the output of the console, there is nothing there still.
